# Find Image using Xpath locator

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have used the below Xpath locator for finding image. But it is not identified : `//img[@src="../images/green_tick.png"]`

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
<form id="j_id_jsp_1879980152_55" name="j_id_jsp_1879980152_55" method="post" action="/aasadmin/pages/customerAccountDetails.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input type="hidden" name="j_id_jsp_1879980152_55" value="j_id_jsp_1879980152_55"> 
  <a href="#" id="j_id_jsp_1879980152_55:adminRedirect" name="j_id_jsp_1879980152_55:adminRedirect" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id_jsp_1879980152_55',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id_jsp_1879980152_55:adminRedirect','containerId':'j_id_jsp_1879980152_0','oncomplete':function(request,event,data){redirectAction(this.form);},'parameters':{'j_id_jsp_1879980152_55:adminRedirect':'j_id_jsp_1879980152_55:adminRedirect'} } );return false;">
    <img src="../images/green_tick.png" height="13">
  </a>
  <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="j_id6" autocomplete="off">
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[showButton(true)//]]></script>
</span>
```

Comment: Where is the _Xpath locator_?

Comment: Maybe it have something to do with JavaScript